# Creating IAM policy in AWS to protect EC2 instances of root users

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-security-group

Working on AWS and am creating a policy whereby a user should create his own instances but should not start, stop or reboot 
instances that were created by the admin/root user. When I test the policy after attaching it to a user it does not work cause the user is not being
able to create an instance. Kindly assist?

```
{
   "Version":"2012-10-17",
   "Statement":[
      {
         "Effect":"Allow",
          "Action":[
            "ec2:RunInstances"
         ],
         "Resource":"*"
      },
      {
         "Effect":"Deny",
         "Action":[
            "ec2:StartInstances",
            "ec2:StopInstances",
            "ec2:RebootInstances"
         ],
         "Resource":"*",
         "Condition":{
            "StringEquals":{
               "ec2:ResourceTag/Owner":"Admin"
            }
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"? Are there any error messages?

Comment: Are the users selecting an IAM Role for use with the instance? If so, they also need `iam:PassRole` permissions, but be careful when writing this policy because they could indirectly obtain Admin-level permissions if they are allowed to assume _every_ IAM Role.

Answer (score 0):

`ec2:RunInstances` Just might not be enough to create an instance. For example, You need describe AMIs to select them. I'd suggest providing List and Read permissions for EC2.

Can you let me know what's the error message you got or where you stuck at to refine your policy?

Below permissions should help yu with the issue.
[image]

Comment: ,, I get this error  **An error occurred describing your selected AMI
You are not authorized to perform this operation.**

Comment: Ah yes, you need List and Read permissions and for your use case, there's no harm in providing that. Once you have the `List` permissions, you should be good to go. I updated the answer